# status 422 Unprocessable entity DELETE json request in Android Client

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, rest

I'm having some trouble with my Android REST client, I can use the get method with no problem to access my Rails API, but when I try to delete something it doesnt seems to connect. I can't find what should the route be called, the normal http://myapi.com/users/1 doesnt seem to work for the delete command.
What should be the URLs forthe DELETE, CREATE, EDIT json commands for a Rails API?
Thanks in advance for your help, this is my first time dealing with APIs and I'm very confused :(

**EDIT**

In the httpresponse im getting in statusLine in statusCode: 422
it's the unprocessable Entity code.

My code for the delete is:

```
    HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        URL_connect_delete= URL + "/"+iduURL;
        Log.e("DELETE", URL_connect_delete);
        HttpDelete delete = new HttpDelete(URL_connect_delete);
        try {
            httpResponse = httpclient.execute(delete);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

iduURL it's the user Id that was selected to be deleted

Comment: What is the request method?  Can you post the request logs.

Comment: my api is hosted in openshift, could that be the reason why it's giving me that error?

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the error by adding line:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

to the user controller of the api.